# SonarQube LDAP configuration

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I have to translate this Apache LDAP configuration

```
AuthType Basic
AuthLDAPBindDN cn=user,dc=cat
AuthLDAPBindPassword password
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://urlldap.com:636/ou=groupsandusers,dc=cat?uid"
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off

<RequireAll>
Require ldap-group cn=sonarqube,ou=develop,ou=groupsandusers,dc=cat
</RequireAll>
```

For sonar ldap plugin

I tried different ways without success

I report my last attempt

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldaps://urlldap.com:636/ou=groupsandusers,dc=cat?uid
ldap.bindDn=cn=user,dc=cat
ldap.bindPassword=password

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=groupsandusers,dc=cat,cn=user

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=cn=sonarqube,ou=develop,ou=groupsandusers,dc=cat
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))
```

When i try with this configuration i receive this error:

org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to retrieve details for user username in < default >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldaps://urlldap.com:636
ldap.bindDn=cn=user,dc=cat
ldap.bindPassword=password

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=groupsandusers,dc=cat
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid={login}))

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=cn=sonarqube,ou=develop,ou=groupsandusers,dc=cat
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))
```

I fix ldap.url, remove the cn=user from ldap.user.baseDn
and add the property ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid={login}))